# Textures working in Blender, but become flat colors when exported to FBX

Tags: texturing, export, unity, .fbx

I have a model that is already UV-mapped, with the materials and textures assigned in Blender, and when I view it with the "Look Dev" viewport shading mode it looks fine:

[image: Blender view]

However, when I export this model to FBX, it does not work properly. Basically, the entire model looks perfectly smooth. This is what it looks like when I import the FBX in Unity, create materials with the textures, and assign those materials to the mesh:

[image: Unity view]

What I have tried so far:

- I tried changing around the materials in Unity. The fur material I created using the texture for this model shows up on other objects. Any other materials I know work elsewhere are still flat colors when applied to this model. So it's not a problem with Unity's materials, it's a problem with the exported model.
- I tried exporting as OBJ instead of FBX. This completely breaks the model since it has multiple materials, and the OBJ ends up only having one material, but at least the texture is visible on it, so it's definitely a problem with the FBX export. I would try GLTF too but the version of Unity I'm using doesn't support it.
- I tried removing all modifiers from the modifier context menu, no change.

Furthermore, for some reason the material context menu's preview section shows all of the materials as flat colors, could this have something to do with it?

[image: Blender materials context menu]

If it helps, here is the Blend file I'm using: https://www.filefaucet.tk/file/?code=NEcghcRD

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures

Comment: I don't think this is the same problem. I'm not trying to get textures inside the FBX, I am intending on creating materials inside of Unity. I just need the UVs to work and such, but it doesn't work with this model.